# Using WMS external SLD with OpenLayers application

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, style, sld

I want to use external SLD file in my OpenLayers application. So I created WMS layer like this:

```
     var ly= new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("mylyer",
        serverurl,
        {
           layers: "PGS:geopoint",
           transparent:true,
           style:"",
           sld: "http://localhost/app/style/point.xml"
        },
        { 
           isBaseLayer: false,
           buffer:0
        });
```

This is not working. This is returning null images. If I send request from browser (not openlayers) it returns error:

**java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Connection refused**

Comment: Is your server running? What do you get when you put `http://localhost/app/style/point.xml` into your browser address bar? Is it different if you add a port, like this: `http://localhost:8080/app/style/point.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http://localhost/` will be interpreted by the WMS server as its own host, but the SLD you want to use is on your app's host (let's say `http://myapp.com/`. So yo will have to change your SLD URL to the app's public URL (using its FQDN), e.g. `http://myapp.com/style/point.xml`:

```
    {
       layers: "PGS:geopoint",
       transparent:true,
       style:"",
       sld: "http://myapp.com/style/point.xml/point.xml"
    },
```

Depending on your WMS implementation, there may be a shortcut if both the WMS and the app run on the same host, e.g. a relative URL or a file URL, but using the FQDN of the app host is the safest way to go.